# CDAP with Azure Data bricks

Tags: databricks, cdap

Has anyone tried using Azure data bricks as the spark cluster for CDAP job processing. CDAP documentation details how to add it to Azure HDInsight, but just wondering is there a way to configure CDAP to point to data bricks spark cluster, is it even possible? OR this kind of integration needs a specific data bricks client connector jar? If anyone has any insights that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of box support for Databricks spark on Azure. But, that said you can develop a new [Cloud Runtime](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/current/en/developer-manual/cloud-runtimes/index.html) that is capable of submitting the jobs to Databricks spark cluster. Here is example of how to write a runtime extension for [Cloud Dataproc](https://github.com/cdapio/cdap/tree/develop/cdap-runtime-ext-dataproc/src/main/java/co/cask/cdap/runtime/spi/provisioner/dataproc) and [EMR](https://github.com/cdapio/cdap/tree/develop/cdap-runtime-ext-emr/src/main/java/co/cask/cdap/runtime/spi/provisioner/emr).

Comment: Let’s us know if you need help. More than happy to help you.